# Use the definition of a derivative to find $f'(x)$ when $f(x) = \frac{x}{(x+1)}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Use the definition of a derivative to find $f'(x)$ when $f(x) = \frac{x}{(x+1)}$
the definition being:  $$\lim_{x \to c} \frac{f(x)−f(c)}{x - c}$$

Comment: Have you attempted it?

Comment: I did, and I got up to Don's second step as shown in the answer. However I'm not sure how he was algebratically able to get to his third step, which is what stopped me.

Answer (score 6):

$$\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}=\frac{\frac x{x+1}-\frac c{c+1}}{x-c}=\frac1{(x+1)(c+1)}\xrightarrow[x\to c]{}\frac1{(c+1)^2}$$

Comment: (+1) Concise. Just $f(c)$ in the numerator would be more correct, if I'm correct...

Comment: Thanks, @JohnnyWesterling: edited. And **only** $\;f(c)\;$ in the numerator is correct...:)

Comment: Of course. You're welcome :)

Comment: Thank you Don, I am curious as to how you got to the third step algebratically?

Comment: @Bygonaut, simplify first the numerator in the second step and you shall see it clearly...

Comment: Well, I'm quite embarassed now. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to the "Oh, damn: how in the world didn't I see that before!" club, @Bygonaut. I'm honorary dictator of the club.

Comment: Well @DonAntonio I think the derivative is $\frac{1}{(c+1)^2}$!

Comment: And you're right, @P.. : there was a typo there when I was writing down the answer and I misled myself and wrote it again at the end. Thanks, edited.